# 2-transitive and 3-transitive Lie groups

Tags: gr.group-theory

Where I can find the classification of 2-transitive and 3-transitive Lie groups?

Comment: Transitive on what?

Answer (score 6):

I found the following by googling :

Kramer, Linus. Two-transitive Lie groups. J. Reine Angew. Math.  563  (2003), 83-113.

also available as arxiv:math/0106108

It completely classifies locally compact sigma-compact groups $G$ acting effectively and 2-transitively on a non totally disconnected space $X$ (hausdorff I presume) : then $G$ is a Lie group, $X$ is a *connected* manifold, and the examples are listed sperately, according to wether $X$ is compact or not.

It remains to extract the 3-transitive cases, which should not be too hard.

Comment: In fact, Corollary 3.4 and Theorem 5.14 (arxiv version) explicitly lists which of these are 3-transitive.